# Testing checkbox click

Tags: testing, qunit

I have started testing my UI using qUnit, so I need to simulate some user interaction. Is it possible to "simulate" a user clicking a checkbox using javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at this:

[Simulate a buttonclick via javascript](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/03/05/simulate-a-button-click-via-javascript/)

It is the other way arround, so i'm not sure if it works on checkboxes too.

Comment: That is the exact answer I have

Answer (score 1):

Thx guyes. I figured it out about two seconds after I posted the question. It was as you say simpler than I had imagined

```
document.getElementById('cb1').click();
```

did the trick

Edit: It seems in IE7 (and perhaps other browsers) the the click method will not actually check the checkbox. So to fully simulate you need to "check" the checkbox before clicking it

```
document.getElementById('cb1').checked=true
document.getElementById('cb1').click();
```